# Swift: Let detail view controller know that array may or may not exist

Tags: swift, uitableview, option-type

So I'm making a recipe diary app for storing recipes. In the `detail view controller`, which has a property `recipe`, there is a `table view` for ingredients which when you open the `detail view controller` you can add ingredients and they appear on a `table view`. The `core data` `relationship` is one to many so the `recipe` `entity` has an `NSOrderedSet` of ingredients and the ingredient has a property recipe.

But in the `numberOfRowsInSection` method when I try to add `return self.recipe?.ingredients.count`, It tells me to put an `!` at the end but when I do it throws an `error` and tells me to remove it.

It says

> Value of optional type Int not unwrapped

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.recipe?.ingredients.count
}
```

I also tried this but it didn't work either

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if self.recipe?.ingredients.count == 0 {            
        return 0        
    }        
    else {
        return self.recipe!.ingredients.count
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried checking if the optional value is equal to 0 with

```
if self.recipe?.ingredients.count == 0
```

This will only return `true` if the value is equal to 0. It will return false if the value is equal to `nil` (which will happen if `recipe` is `nil`.

Instead try to determine whether your `recipes` is `nil`

```
if let recipe = self.recipe {
  //Check if self.recipe is not equal to nil and assign the value to recipe if it is not equal to nil.
  return recipe.ingredients.count
}else{
  /return 0 if recipe is equal to nil
  return 0
}
```

Comment: If an answer on Stack Overflow helped you and/or solved your problem please mark it as the "answer". Use the checkmark under the vote buttons to mark the answer which helped you solve your problem. This will help others with the same question find the answer easier.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work but try

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if let recepies = self.recipe? {
        return recepies.ingredients.count
     }

    return 0
}
```

This checks for the existence of the recipe array, if it exists then will return the count of the ingredients, otherwise will return 0.

Comment: When answering a question please include why your answer will help the poster. Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime.